# Postgres aggregate results based on 2 columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, group-by

In postgres 9.6 I have a table that includes these 3 columns.

```
id | val1 | val2
------------------
1  | x    | 1
1  | x    | 2
1  | x    | 3
1  | y    | 4
2  | y    | 1
2  | y    | 2
```

Can I use aggregate functions to turn it into this?

```
id | 
------------------------------
1  | { x: [1, 2, 3], y: [4] }
2  | { y: [1, 2] }
```

Or if what I'm looking for isn't possible, something like below could work too. Or anything that would allow me to transform the results into the above in my application code.

```
id | 
------------------------------
1  | [ {x: 1}, {x: 2}, {x: 3}, {y: 4} ]
2  | [ {y: 1}, {y: 2} ]
```

I know I can do something like `select id, array_agg(val2) from mytable group by val2`, but that only groups  by `val2` and returns something like

```
id | 
------------------
1  | [1, 2, 3, 4]
2  | [1, 2]
```

Comment: Did any of the answer solve your problem? You haven't commented on any.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with:

```
SELECT
    id, json_object_agg(val1, aaa)
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        id, val1, json_agg(val2) AS aaa
    FROM
        t
    GROUP BY
        id, val1
    ) AS q 
GROUP BY
    id;
```

```
id | json_object_agg               
-: | :-----------------------------
 1 | { "x" : [1, 2, 3], "y" : [4] }
 2 | { "y" : [1, 2] }
```

You can find the needed definitions to produce this result at *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=6b6c86ab6db0e335ba61c738a93198e1)*

You'll be using these two functions:

- json_agg
- json_object_agg

The documentation can be found at [9.20. Aggregate Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html) in PostgreSQL doc

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way using [jsonb_agg and jsonb_object_agg functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html)

```
with the_table(id , val1 , val2) as(
    select 1 ,'x',1 union all
    select 1  ,'x', 2 union all
    select 1  ,'x', 3 union all
    select 1  ,'y', 4 union all
    select 2 ,'y', 1 union all
    select 2 ,'y', 2
)


select id, jsonb_object_agg(val1, arr) from (
    select id, val1, jsonb_agg(val2) as arr
    from the_table
    group by id, val1
)t
group by id
```

Answer (score 1):

And yet another useful piece of code inspired by SO question:

```
drop aggregate if exists jsonb_objarr_agg(text, anyelement);
drop function if exists jsonb_objarr_agg_func(jsonb, text, anyelement);
create function jsonb_objarr_agg_func(jsonb, text, anyelement) returns jsonb immutable language sql as $$
  select
    jsonb_set(
      $1,
      array[$2],
      coalesce(
        case
          when jsonb_typeof($1->$2) <> 'array' then to_jsonb(array[$1->$2])
          else $1->$2
        end, 
        '[]'::jsonb) || to_jsonb($3), true);
$$;

select jsonb_objarr_agg_func('{"a":1}', 'a', 2);

create aggregate jsonb_objarr_agg(text, anyelement) (
  sfunc = jsonb_objarr_agg_func,
  stype = jsonb,
  initcond = '{}');

with t(i, v1, v2) as (values
    (1, 'x', 1),
    (1, 'x', 2),
    (1, 'x', 3),
    (1, 'y', 4),
    (2, 'y', 1),
    (2, 'y', 2))
select
  i,
  jsonb_objarr_agg(v1, v2)
from t
group by i;
```

```
╔═══╤════════════════════════════╗
║ i │      jsonb_objarr_agg      ║
╠═══╪════════════════════════════╣
║ 1 │ {"x": [1, 2, 3], "y": [4]} ║
║ 2 │ {"y": [1, 2]}              ║
╚═══╧════════════════════════════╝
```

This aggregate allows to make `jsonb` with first parameter as keys and also aggregate the second parameter into arrays.

If you need the `json` type instead then you can easily replace `jsonb` to `json` in this code.

<kbd>[live demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=3572f14696afd07a274ecf790f32baeb)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I think the following does what you want:

```
select id, json_agg(json_build_object(val1, val2s ))
from (select id, val1, array_agg(val2) as val2s
      from t
      group by id, val1
     ) t
group by id;
```